# Is it possible to add an index to a column? To order them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add an index or something to a column, so when a column has a higher index, it would be below of those with a lower index?

For example, http://jsfiddle.net/BL3M7/8/ :

HTML:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="block" style="height: 50px">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">7</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">8</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">9</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">10</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">11</div>');
    }, 2000);
})
```

CSS :

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.block-container {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%; 
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I want boxes 7,8,9,10 to be below of boxes 4,6,5.

Comment: You need to use Javascript to reorder the DOM elements.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an MVC style design, in which your view only presents the data held in the data model, and thus would not only be orderable, but would be re-orderable too.

Comment: What about adding them into another separate '.block-container'?

Comment: why not use jquery tablesorter?  See http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: @r3mus: I am sorry, but I absolutely don't follow you.

Comment: @user2310289: I think it's apples and oranges.

Comment: @good_evening you mention `add an index a column` so I assumed table.  A type of Apple I think

Answer (score -1):

*I take it you mean something resembling this:*

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bUs5/)

All the code is unchanged except this.

### CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.block-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

### Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">7</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">8</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">9</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">10</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">11</div>');
    }, 2000);
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="block" style="height: 50px">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
</div>
```

This is only what I interpret your question to be aiming at for a result.  If I'm wrong I apologize.  I understand you are using columns but if this is the look you want, then columns are not necessary.

Comment: This does not work.  if you add `$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">7</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">8</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">2</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">10</div>');
        $('.block-container').append('<div class="block">11</div>');
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: Using Chrome and Firefox, both prove this successful.  Please clarify @user2310289 - I just updated with all the code used and it all shows as expected (3 columns with 4 5 6 above 7 8 9 10)

Comment: Maybe I am mis-reading the question (again), but if there was originally no `block 2` and you add a `block 2` it should insert between block 1 and 3

Comment: lol there is already a block 2 in the original set (it goes 1 2 3 4 5 6) I think you switched block 9 with 2 for some reason. the new set goes 7 8 9 10 11

Comment: in your html delete `block 2` in you JS change `block 9` to `block 2` - The new `block 2` it should insert between block 1 and 3 - no?

Comment: negative.  That is simply a text value, not the index.  In order for it to be placed there, you would have to remove the set from the DOM and re-create it (it being `block-container`) and then re-insert into the DOM where it was previously located.  Unfortunately this means you would also have to know which block was removed and where it was.  So in this case you would sort the blocks by the `$('.block').text()` before re-inserting into the DOM, giving them proper index assignments.

Comment: Well, I think this is what the OP wants.